# MVC [Autorize] plus Roles from string

Tags: model-view-controller, authorize

Hey I got some idea but problem is i can't make this work.

in MVC we can use `[Authorize]` to "protect" some actions/controllers, we can make next step and give some persmission for a Roles and Users.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Boss", User="Secretary"]
```

This working good but its kind of bad becaue in real life we dont know who will have rights for this. So idea was make strings of Roles and Users and back to authorize to make Microsoft magic on this.

```
[Authoize(Role=RoleString(), User=UserString())]
```

Ofcourse, its not working, how make this work?

Comment: If you are talking about ASP.Net's interpretation of MVC, then please, us the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that AuthorizeAttribute expects a constant for both the User and the Role strings.  You will need to make a CustomAuthorizeAttribute that is something like what is found in [this blog post](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/09/CustomAuthorizationASPNETMVCFrameworkAuthorizeAttribute.aspx).

So lets say you have a string that you store in your web.config that is something like this:

```
<add key="authorizedUsers" value="Dave,Chuck,Sally" />
```

and then you have your custom authorize attribute that would be something like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public IAuthorizationService _authorizationService { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var users = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authorizedUsers"].Split(',');
        if users.Contains(user.Identity.Name)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _authorizationService.Authorize(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Note that I threw this together rather quickly so it is not tested. You can easily modify this to get user or group names from a database so that it can be fully dynamic.